# Ubuntu 2.6.35 vmlinux image for kernel profiling using oprofile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oprofile

HI i want to run profiling on Kernel using Oprofile but it requires uncompressed vmlinux image and ubuntu 10.10 provides vmlinuz which is stripped and compressed. Pls help

Comment: Is using Oprofile mandatory ? Do you know about the perf tool ?Is your question "How to profile the kernel", or "How to get an uncompressed linux image from an ubuntu installation". Please clarify your question

Comment: Hi...NO restriction as it comes to tool but should be free. my objective is to get profiling info abt kernel..But i think that debug symbol info is a must for profiling kernel and ultimately it boils down to getting uncompressed linux image from ubuntu installation

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rebuild the kernel from source or find an uncompressed copy of vmlinux. The vmlinuz file is stripped of symbols along with the ELF header to save space, and are needed for oprofile.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/309589/244984) for how to install an uncompressed (debug) version of your kernel.